# Magento product detailed page Varien form hidden field validation not working

Tags: form-validation, prototype-js, magento1.9.3

I have work with Magento1.9.3, then in my product detailed page i have added some hidden dropdown fields.

When i was used the Prototype(1.7.0) js, the hidden field validation was wroked without any issue, but after i upgrade the 1.7.3 version the hidden dropdown field is not working.

Kindly share your idea for fix the issue, thanks in advanc for your support